# Type Within Type using Class Module

Tags: excel, vba, class, types, properties

I'm trying to construct a type within a type using Class Modules.

I have a standard code module with my Types, and a Class Module with Set/Let/Get Properties for each type. I then have one as an example of how I'm trying to use them.

This method works with one type, but not with a type within a type. When setting the second type in the standard module, I get a

> "Compile error: Method or data member not found".

---

### Class module 1, called clsMod

```
Option Explicit
Private Memento As clsMo2

Friend Sub SetMemento(NewMemento As clsMo2)
    Memento = NewMemento
End Sub

Friend Property Set clsTes2(value As clsMo2)
    Memento.m_clsTes2 = value 'This is where it errors, with "m_clsTes2" highlighted
End Property
Friend Property Get clsTes2() As clsMo2
    clsTes2 = Memento.m_clsTes2
End Property
```

---

### Class Module 2, called clsMo2

```
Option Explicit
Private Memento2 As MyTyp2
Friend Sub SetMemento2(NewMemento As MyTyp2)
        Memento2 = NewMemento
End Sub

Public Property Let stri(value As String)
    Memento2.stri = value
End Property
Public Property Get stri() As String
    stri = Memento2.stri
End Property
```

---

### Standard code module with Types

```
Type MyTyp2
    stri      As String
End Type

Type MyType
    m_clsTes2 As MyTyp2
End Type
```

---

### Standard code module with Sub

```
Option Explicit
Public clsTest As clsMod
Public clsTes2  As clsMo2

Public Sub Variables()
    Set clsTest = New clsMod
    Set clsTest.clsTes2 = New clsMo2 'This line triggers the error
    clsTest.clsTes2.stri = "TestString" 'This is what I want to get to be able to do
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no member variable or method called `m_clsTes2` in your `clsMo2` class

Comment: You do NOT want to expose public user-defined types like this. That said in order for `clsTest` to have a `clsTes2` member, the `clsMod` class would need to expose a `Public Property Get clsTes2() As clsMod2`. Protip: drop the Hungarian Notation prefixing scheme, it's really not helping here.

Comment: Also your object-type properties are all missing `Set` in the bodies of the methods.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers! I'm a complete novice when it comes to using Types and Class Modules so your feedback is really helpful.
@Sorceri thanks. Do I need that when I've got the elements in the type?
@MathieuGuindon thanks. Would you suggest I declare my types as Private in the class modules instead? Or how to avoid exposing public UDTs? Also my clsMod already has a `Public Property Get clsTes2() as clsMo2`, am I doing something else wrong? I shall drop the prefixing, apologies for any damage to your eyes!
@TimWilliams thanks. Does having Set clstest..etc in Variables sub not do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be over-complicating things. Try with a simpler example first.

See if you can follow the skeleton code provided below

### Class1

```
Option Explicit

Private m_name As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_name = "Default"
End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = m_name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal x as string)
    m_name = x
End Property
```

### Class2

```
Option Explicit

Private m_info As Class1

Public Property Get Info() As Class1
    Set Info = m_info
End Property

Public Property Set Info(ByRef X As Class1)
    Set m_info = X
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_info = New Class1
End Sub
```

### Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestCode()
    
    Dim t As New Class2
    Debug.Print t.Info.Name
    ' Default

    t.Info.Name = "Another"
 
End Sub
```